# Xrandr orientation is correct, pointer is rotated 180 degrees

Tags: mouse, display, touchscreen

I finally manages to install Ubuntu on Myria MY8307.
I have two big issues, probably related.

1. To have the screen in the right orientation for landscape use with the keyboard, I need to apply xrandr -o right. Afterward, the screen display the current orientation but the pointer is rotated 180 degrees along with the system of coordinates. If want to click something from upper left corner, I need to click on the lower right corner for example. I tried using this script and setting a different Coordinate Transformation Matrix, but none of these helped me.
2. I installed the following [driver](https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware) for my touchscreen. The cursor moves reversed on Y, the whole screen moves the cursor in 1/4 out of height and width. While dragging my screen making selection, I can see my selection in the top left corner, while the mouse pointer actually moving in the bottom right corner.

Any ideas on how to fix my issues? I would also like to note that I tried to use iio-sensor-proxy and then to remove it but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
xinput and xrandr
```

to get the ID of the mouse (11 in this case) and the output monitor (eDP for me) and note that it might change on a reboot,

```
xinput map-to-output 11 eDP    
                                                                                                            And you might have to apply a transformation for the coordinates
```

This was mine for the rotate right

```
xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
```

All in all the one liner for the touchscreen digitiser pen was

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate right &&  xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 11 eDP
```

Comment: I already tried setting the Coordinate Transformation Matrix. That didn't fix my issue. Sure, the mouse was now moving correctly but cursor's image and the coordination points for my mouse position were still upside down.

Something else that I noticed, for some reason, Raspbian Desktop is the only distro that get the display orientation and movement right but leaves me with no bluetooth/wifi. That and the install is messes up my screen, so it is still not usable for anything else but live USB boot.

Comment: perhaps you could reveal the script  what in your question you refer to as "I tried using this script a" . another idea might be to choose wayland or x0rg .

Answer (score 0):

You can try zooming in the desktop a bit.
That worked for me.